# dynamic define and allocate pointers

Tags: c, pointers, macros

I want to dynamically define and allocate pointers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define def_var(type,name,i) type name##i
#define var(name,i) name##i
void main(){
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    def_var(float,*ww,i)=NULL;
  }
  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    var(ww,i)=(float *)malloc(100);
  }
}
```

But when I compile it, lots of error come up. Can anybody help fix it?

Comment: There is no point telling us there are errors if you don't include them in your question! But it's obvious the problem is that you're declaring variables in your first `for` loop and trying to use them in the second one.

Comment: Also you're using `malloc` incorrectly. You need to specify the size in bytes of what you want to allocate, so to allocate 100 float you want `malloc(sizeof(float)*100)`

Comment: @Acorn no - it's 10 `float *`, but OP has put the * in the wrong place.

Comment: It's pointless to use macros for making your code less readable. Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)? What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using a macro to create numbered variables instead of just using an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you're trying to do. Preprocessor macros are expanded at compile time, they can't depend on run-time variable values. So

```
def_var(float,*ww,i)=NULL;
```

is expanded into

```
float *wwi = NULL;
```

It doesn't, and can't, replace `i` with the value of the variable, it just performs text substitution.

Also, variable declarations have block scope, so any variables declared inside the `for` loop go away when the loop finishes.

Just declare an array of pointers.

```
float *ww[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ww[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(float *));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ww` is supposed to represent 10 arrays of 100 floats each (known numbers at compile time), then just use a multi-dimensional array:

```
float ww[10][100];
```

and index accordingly when used (eg: `ww[7][93] = 6;`).

If 'ww' ***must*** contain dynamically allocated pointers as you say, then use (where each element is a *pointer to an array of 100 floats*)

```
float (*ww[10]) [100];
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    ww[i]=malloc(sizeof(float)*100);
  }
```

and index accordingly when used (eg: `(*(ww[7]))[93] = 6;` or `ww[7]->[93] = 6;`).

Remember to free each when done.

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    free(ww[i]);
  }
```

***Caution***: Remember `malloc` will not intialize the newly allocated memory - that is up to you! Strongly recommended to use `calloc` instead to zero-out the memory instead, so it is in a known state.